# Getting a radio button immediately by clicking a label with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some radio buttons styled to be hidden with the labels visible and styled as I want them.

The problem is when I click a label I don't get the radio button's value on the first click.

If you look here you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/bQwtK/1/

Is there a way to get the value on the first click?

**ANSWER-**
Thanks to asawyer and blocco- http://jsfiddle.net/bQwtK/14/

Comment: It works for me in Chrome and Firefox (clicking on each label selects the corresponding radio button, first time and every time - I assume that's what you want?). What browser are you using?

Comment: This outa do it. http://jsfiddle.net/bQwtK/4/

Comment: Thank you, linked the wrong example but you got what I meant! Thank you aswayer and blocco :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value with the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lq_blocco/bQwtK/9/):

```
$(".label_size").click(function()
{
   alert($("#"+$(this).attr("for")).val());
})
```

Comment: `this.getAttribute` ? OP is using jQuery, use `$(this).attr('for')`

Comment: Works! I messed up the version I linked in my question but you got what I meant! Exactly what I wanted, thank you :)

Comment: @blocco: that's because I'm an idiot, and forgot that in the DOM/plain-JavaScript `for` is `htmlFor`: [`alert($('#' + this.htmlFor).val())` works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bQwtK/15/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code was broken - you missed a closing brace in your JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/bQwtK/5/

Clicking the labels works.  If you want the value of the radio buttons, remember that the click event refers to the label, not the radio button.  You'll have to access the "for" attribute to get the radio button, and then get its value.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya: your jsfiddle don't give any alert please see correct **demo** here": http://jsfiddle.net/NEu97/2/ & thank a sawyer : http://jsfiddle.net/NEu97/5/

Please let me know how it goes & hope this helps, :)

**Jquery Code**

```
$(".label_size").click(function()
{
   alert(' clicked value =' + $(this).text());
   alert(' correspong value =' + $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).val());
   alert("D");
});

    ​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio">(This is styled to be hidden)
   <input name="size" class="radio_size" type="radio" id="radio_size_small" value="small "/>
   <input name="size" class="radio_size" type="radio" id="radio_size_medium" value="medium"/>
   <input name="size" class="radio_size" type="radio" id="radio_size_large" value="large"/>
</div>

<div class="radio_labels">
   <label class="label_size" for="radio_size_small" id="label_size_small">SMALL</label>
   <label class="label_size" for="radio_size_medium" id="label_size_medium">MEDIUM</label>
   <label class="label_size" for="radio_size_large" id="label_size_large">LARGE</label>
</div>
​
```

Comment: This gets the label's text, NOT the value of the corresponding radio button